# Sun Light Not Illuminating Anything

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, error

My sun light isn't illuminating the scene at all, it
s all black and I'm not sure why. Could you please help? [This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DD8bUKdcjC0v4GwXAY9Uh9VIQAQm0Db5/view?usp=share_link) is the link to the .blend file.

Screenshot of the issue. I am in rendered view, and this is all that shows.
[image: This is a screenshot of the issue I'm having]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Will do.

Comment: You need to pack your textures into the blend file before you upload it via File > External Data > Pack Resources in Blender. Then upload it to https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on that page. We'll then be able to see what's going on.

Comment: Oh, alright. I'll do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your light is working just fine. It's the material on your sphere object that is giving you trouble. Objects that have non-working or no materials will render as black, in this instance making it seem as though your light was not working.

Diffuse shaders are not compatible with the volume input of the output node, and will render as black. To correct this, move the shader output to the surface input of the output node, and things should render as expected.

[image]

Comment: Ohhh... thanks! That should fix the problem. I must've missed something in the tutorial.